# How xls file size is determined?

Tags: python, csv, size, xls

It depends on data type or number of characters..?If i convert a csv file into xls file,file size of .xls will be 3X times of csv file.So it depends on what format we are saving as well.?Any idea on how much bytes needed to hold  a character in xls(csv file ---1 character---1 bytes)

Comment: `XLS` is a binary format, and does not increase in linear form depending on content. In fact, an empty XLS file is (on my machine) 25600 bytes. Adding 3 cells content does not increase the file size at all. So the answer is more complex.  I don't think you can say firmly that "XLS is 3x the CSV".

Comment: Have a look at the `xls` file structure specification. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xls/cd03cb5f-ca02-4934-a391-bb674cb8aa06

Comment: While a Microsoft Excel worksheet (XLS) binary file will typically be larger than an equivalent comma-separated values (CSV) text file, this is not always the case and depends heavily on the type of content as well as the version of Excel used.

Comment: @MyICQ---Yes i also saved empty xls file it tooks same memory for me..

Comment: @ljmc-I didnt see related to how the size of xls file determined there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on number of rows,columns and sheets we are trying to add.Even an empty rows occupies a some bytes and char occupies 1 bytes(space,spl characters as well).I have checked manually by iterating xml sheet by adding rows,columns and sheets.
Workbook-314bytes ,Rows - 35 bytes ,columns- 43 bytes ,worksheet-73 bytes & char- 1bytes.